# Can't setup Anyconnect/OpenConnect VPN proxy on Linux (Manjaro) - proxy is not on https

Tags: linux, vpn, manjaro, cisco-anyconnect, openconnect

Main issue is that when using openConnect, I can't setup proxy, since it's like

http://setpac.mycorp.com

and openConnect will refuse to connect to it

```
openconnect vpn.mycorp.com -P setpac.mycorp.com
POST https://vpn.mycorp.com/
getaddrinfo failed for host 'setpac.mycorp.com': Name or service not known
Failed to open HTTPS connection to vpn.mycorp.com
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

When not specifying proxy, I will connect but can't access internet resources without proxy. AnyConnect linux client doesn't provide settings, and ~/.anyconnect profile ignores vpn setting inside it. Any idea how to override or force http connection for proxy ?

I've tried creating a profile in /opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/MyCustomProfile.xml
with

```
<AnyConnectProfile>
    <ClientInitialization>
        <ProxySettings>Override
    <PublicProxyServerAddress UserControllable="true">setpac.mycorp.com:80</PublicProxyServerAddress>
        </ProxySettings>
    </ClientInitialization>
</AnyConnectProfile>
```

But anyconnect client doesn't use it.

On Windows 10 I can connect when setting up proxy in windows proxy settings which doesn't require https. Thanks.

Comment: So the proxy is supposed to go _after_ the VPN connection, not _for_ the VPN connection itself, yes?

Comment: Yes, proxy is required after connecting to VPN to have access to intranet and internet. I can connect to vpn and authenticate without any proxy, but can't use it for internet connection afterwards.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the -P option I believe. It is used by openconnect to make VPN connection, it is not for applications to use afterwards. You need to setup proxy as you normally do after VPN has been established.